# How to write selenium script for taking random alphanumeric number from a list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, random, uuid

I need help in selenium script. I need to take random alphanumeric values from my table list. How I can do it in selenium? I want to use

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

This in my selenium script. But I don't know how to use?

Comment: I can't see your selenium script.

Comment: I can't see the language tag for the selenium script.

Comment: How can be the generated `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` match with the values in your _table list_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it won't be possible to match the newly generated `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` with any of the the predefined values within your table list.

However, to generate and send a *random number* to the *Search Box* on *Google Home Page* you can use the following solution:

- *Code Block*:

  ```
  import java.util.UUID;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class RandomNumbers_GoogleSearchBox {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q"))).sendKeys(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: random_UUID]